# How can I sort a file by word frequency?

Tags: sort

I have a file containing a list of words, e.g. `list.txt` contains:

```
carrot
apple
pen
ukulele
pen
cinnamon
carrot
carrot
```

How do I sort this file so that the words which appear the most in it go to the top, and duplicates are removed?

e.g. I'd like `list.txt` to contain this after sorting:

```
carrot
pen
apple
cinnamon
ukulele
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normaly, I would use

```
:%! sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

but this is a shell depended answer.

Using only Vim language or ex-commands in Vim is a little bit more difficult and it is very nicely described on wikia in [Word frequency statistics for a file](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Word_frequency_statistics_for_a_file).

Inspired by that article it is possible to replicate the output of `:%! sort | uniq -c | sort -nr` with

```
:%s/^\+/1\t/g
:sort
:g/^\c\(.\+\)\n\1$/norm! ^yiwj@"^Akdd
:sort! n
```

The `^A` represents <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> and is inserted as <kbd>CTRL-V</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL-A</kbd> (or if you use <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> for paste, press <kbd>Ctrl-Q</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd>).

Comment: your solution seems to be prepending numbers, I don't want these.

Comment: So just delete them :-) You can use any way you want. Exampli gratia, `:%s/\d\t// `.